# The matrix representation of an interval graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, combinatorial-optimization, integer-programming

It is well-known that many classes of graphs have matrix representations that can be written concisely.  For example,

- The set of all directed acyclic graphs consists of binary matrices $x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ that can be permuted to take an upper triangular form,
- The set of perfect bipartite matchings on $n+n$ nodes consists of binary matrices $x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ such that $\sum_i x_{ij} = \sum_j x_{ij} = 1$,
- The set of spanning trees on $n$ nodes consists of symmetric binary matrices $x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ such that $$\sum_{i,j} x_{ij} = 2(n-1)$$ and $$\sum_{(i,j):i,j\in S}x_{ij} \leq    2(|S|-1)$$ for all proper subsets $S\subset\{1,\dots,n\}$, and
- The set of all Hamiltonian circuits through $n$ nodes consists of symmetric binary matrices $x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ such that $$\sum_j x_{ij} = 2$$ for all $i$ and $$\sum_{i\in S, j\not\in S} x_{ij} \geq 2$$ for all proper subsets $S\subset\{1,\dots,n\}$.

I am wondering if there exists a similar representation for interval graphs, especially interval graphs of bounded chromatic number?  The literature I have reviewed always deals with constructing the configuration of intervals explicitly, and I am curious if there is a natural combinatorial representation that I could use in, say, integer programming.

Comment: The clique-vertex incidence matrix of any interval graph has the consecutive-ones property, i.e., the columns can be permuted such that all the 1's in each row appear consecutively. Such matrices are unimodular, so when they arise as constraint matrices in linear programs, the points of the corresponding polyhedron are integral. Since interval graphs are perfect, the chromatic number and clique number coincide, so a bound on the chromatic number is a bound on the number of 1's in any row of the clique-vertex incidence matrix. But, in some sense, this matrix constructs the intervals explicitly.